# "No installation candidate", "unable to find source package" on MySQLdb install, Ubuntu 16

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a script that connects to a MySQL database. Using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I don't care how it's done, I just want it done. After doing some research, I found MySQLdb to be a good package to download to connect to MySQL through python.

I've found a number of step-by-step tutorials for installing mysqldb with seemingly varying commond prompt commands (which makes little sense to me). Here's an example of one I just tried following:

https://web.archive.org/web/20180115170236/http://www.palaeopi.org.uk/index.php/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-using-python-part-1/

When I try to run step 3, I get:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> E: Unable to find a source package for python-mysqldb

...which makes me think some package lists on the OS are out of date?

I looked at this page:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm

and tried running

`$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

but get

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Package libmysqlclient-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> However the following packages replace it:
>
> python
>
> E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
>
> E: Package 'libmysqlclient-dev' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question probably should have been posted in "Unix & Linux" or "Ask Ubuntu"

Anyway, per [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140119/every-package-has-no-installation-candidate), I used [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) to regenerate my /etc/apt/**sources.list** file by checking all the boxes under "Ubuntu Branches" and "Ubuntu Updates" and clicking "Generate List" at the bottom.

Then copied & pasted the output to my **sources.list** file and ran:
`sudo apt-get update`

After doing that, the following commands were successful:

`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev`

`sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Comment: "sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev" worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Dumb question but did you try this before you tried the install?

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: You might get some  help from the answers [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu) here.

Comment: I know, that's why I put it in the answers instead. Just helping any way I can.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this source, and apt-get update&apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main